# Equivalent to x_num_rows function for Interbase/Firebird?

Tags: php, firebird, interbase

Since I'm switching from odbc functions to ibase functions in php i found that there is no 'ibase_num_rows' like function to use to count the rows from a result.

Is there any function that gives the rowcount of a result in PHP?

Comment: Why switch from one to another single-DB-interface? There's [PDO::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) - depending on if the driver supports that. And you could just use `SELECT COUNT(…)` with any API. What's that obsession with num_rows anyway?

Comment: Its easier to use a num_rows function becasue when using `SELECT COUNT(...)` you need another query.

Comment: Often a subquery suffices, if the count is really important. Just asking, because a widespread newcomer abuse of _num_rows is double-checking for results ≥0 - even though simply fetching the first row would already reveal that.